# On hover replace text not working (Jquery)

Tags: php, jquery

I'm unable to get one of my functions to work. My assumption is that there is a 'scope' issue due to the fact the function works when used in the same file it modifies. Anyway here is the function and fiddle.
The function as the title suggests should replace text on hover and 'off-hover' put the original text back. The code snippet below works, but when used as I'm trying to(fiddle) it does not work.
 http://jsfiddle.net/s4q8bva6/3/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<a href="#" class="open">01 - System Overview and System Manager</a>


<script>
$("a.open").hover(
    function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data('initialText', $this.text());
        $this.text("Click to return to previous page");
    },
    function() {
        var $this = $(this); // caching $(this)
        $this.text($this.data('initialText'));
    }
);        
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

EDITS:Update

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>PHP File Tree Demo</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="styles/default/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <!-- Makes the file tree(s) expand/collapsae dynamically -->
    <script src="php_file_tree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

    <h1>File Tree </h1>     


    <h2>Browsing Training Videos...</h2>

    <?php

     //This links the user to http://example.com/?file=filename.ext
    //echo php_file_tree('Training/', "http://example.com/?file=[link]/");

    include("php_file_tree.php");
    // This links the user to http://example.com/?file=filename.ext and only shows image files
    $allowed_extensions = array("htm");
    echo php_file_tree("Training/", "http://URL/files/[link]", $allowed_extensions);
    echo "This is a TEST";
    // This displays a JavaScript alert stating which file the user clicked on
    //echo php_file_tree("demo/", "javascript:alert('You clicked on [link]');");            
    ?>

    <!-- This function collapses the li under an open li-->





    <!-- Togles all 'Other' Top Level il elements on click-->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
var col = 2
$(".pft-directory").click(function () {
    $(".pft-directory").toggle("fast");
    $(this).toggle("fast");
    if (col > 1) {
        $(".php-file-tree").css("columns", "1", "-webkit-columns", "1");
        col = 1;
    } else {
        $(".php-file-tree").css("columns", "2", "-webkit-columns", "2");
        col = 2;
    }

});
$(".open").hover(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('initial-text', $this.text());
    $this.text("Click to return to previous page");
},

function () {
    var $this = $(this); // caching $(this)
    $this.text($this.data('initial-text'));
});
});         
    </script>       

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It does not work in jsFiddle cause you did not included jQuery library

Comment: I don't think the jquery data allows for camel case properties

Comment: exactly. you cannot camelCase data attributes. also you have invalid characters at the end of your JS file/tab `-- >`

Comment: o.o it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/351/

Comment: My mistake for not including the jquery lib. The solution for the data attribute did resolve my issue in JS fiddle but not in my environment. My html is generated form within .php file. I've copied this above "EDITS:Update"